# Is there any equivalent in C# and Java for the C method _strtod_l?

Tags: java, c#, c

C method _strtod_l  can convert string "13.361389" to double value 13.361389000000001 , is there equivalent in C#  and Java also can get the same result? I found the Convert.ToDouble in C# cannot do it.

[image]

Comment: In java `Double.parseDouble(Str)` can be used

Comment: Java: `double d = Double.parseDouble("13.361389");`

Comment: `Double.Parse` in C# is one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

For C# you can use `Double.Parse("13.361389", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

For Java you can use `Double.parseDouble("13.361389")`

Comment: I test it with following code , and  the result for value1 is still 13.361389 instead of 13.361389000000001. 
   double value1 = Double.Parse("13.361389", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: why  _strtod_l covert it to  13.361389000000001 instead of 13.361389?

Comment: Indeed, I tried in visual c++ 2015 and it gives your number. Sorry, I don't know why. I can remove my answer if you want.